# How to Force Thread Dump in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, memory-leaks, weblogic

I'm launching a Weblogic application inside Eclipse via the BEA Weblogic Server v9.2 runtime environment. If this were running straight from the command-line, I'd do a ctrl-BREAK to force a thread dump. Is there a way to do it in Eclipse?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Indeed (thanks VonC to point to the SO thread), Dustin, in a comment to his message, points to [jstack](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstack.html).

I have run a little Java application (with GUI) in Eclipse, I can see the related javaw.exe in Windows' process manager and its PID, 7088 (it is even simpler in Unix, of course).

If I type at a command prompt `jstack 7088`, I have the wanted stack dump per thread.
Cool.

Would be better if we could do that directly from Eclipse, but that's already useful as is.

Comment: Warning: we do not know the platform used to launch eclipse/weblogic: if it is windows, jstack is not supported with java1.5, and only partially supported with 1.6

Comment: it's easy to launch external tools directly from Eclipse: menu "Run -> External Tools" or the toolbar button next to the "run" button (add a string_prompt for the PID)

Answer (score 7):

You can do it when you are in debug mode: go to the debug view in the debug perspective, click on the process you have launched and click on pause, you will get a graphical stack of all your processes.

Note : this also works when using remote debugging, you do not need to launch weblogic from eclipse, you can launch it on its own, open the debugging ports and create a "remote java application debug configuration" for it.

Comment: yep, but you need to add this to the JVM:  set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8001,server=y,suspend=n

Answer (score 7):

check SendSignal:
http://www.latenighthacking.com/projects/2003/sendSignal/

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse Wiki: [How to Report a Deadlock](http://wiki.eclipse.org/How_to_report_a_deadlock) lists all possible options of creating a thread dump in Eclipse. Depending on the concrete situation, one or the other may work better -- my personal favorite on Windows is the Adaptj Stacktrace tool.

Answer (score 2):

[StackTrace](http://www.adaptj.com/main/stacktrace) is another option that you could try. From the features:

> Thread dump for Java processes running
>   as a *Windows* service (like Tomcat, for
>   example), started with *javaw.exe*,
>   applets running inside any browser or
>   JVMs embedded inside another process.
>   StackTrace works on Windows, Linux and
>   Mac OS X.

Answer (score 2):

if you prefer UI based solution [visualvm](http://visualvm.java.net/) might be a good choice. (it's advantage is also that it's distributed with JDK)

To take the thread dump in visualvm:

1. connect to process (remote or local) and
2. go for `Threads` (tab) -> `Thread Dump` (button)

Comment: It is worth to mention, that user must launch `jvisualvm` supplied with java machine. On my linux machine it is in: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/jvisualvm`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to launch your eclipse with java.exe instead of javaw.exe (in your [eclipse.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-eclipse-34-jvm-settings#144349)) ?

That might give you the console you need, as described in [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=13524) and in [this message](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/newsLists/news.eclipse.platform/msg15120.html).

Other ideas (in term of java options) could be derived from this [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66104/why-does-tomcat-55-with-java-14-running-on-windows-xp-32-bit-suddenly-hang).

Answer (score 0):

You can connect through the JVisualVM and get a thread dump. Just right click on the application node from the Applications tree and select "Thread dump"

Answer (score 0):

On linux at least you can do a `ps -ef | grep java` to get the PID and then do a `kill -3 PID` and it will output it to the Eclipse console.