# How to find out why Eclipse is freezing?

Tags: java, eclipse

Every time i run any junit or any job [ spring-batch ] from eclipse. It hangs for around 10-15 mins. After that everything goes fine.
Now, i would like to know in such cases what are the steps you take or what are the tools you use to rectify the problem.

Till now i am unable to resolve the problem. Please help. Should i post the Thread dump here?

Comment: Is your DNS-configuration 100% correct?

Comment: yes! or may be i think so. Till now i am unable to resolve the problem. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243298/how-to-force-thread-dump-in-eclipse) on SO, try: http://wiki.eclipse.org/How_to_report_a_deadlock

Answer (score 0):

If you have a significantly large project try turning off **Build Automatically** which would definitely slow eclipse and seemingly hang eclipse when trying to run a junit.

Access it from Project > Build Automatically