# Google App Engine App with JPA deployment hangs

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, datanucleus

I have a java GAE web app with datanucleus as the JPA provider. When deploying locally on my machine - the deployment hangs (takes minutes). Looking at the task manager I have a javac process running. Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: i get this a lot too. it ends up just coming good by cancelling and rollback and try again. some times it even takes a few goes. i have suspecions that the app isnt starting properly (and sometimes this is founded [check your logs]) but other times it just takes forever for some reason.

Comment: What do you mean by "deploying locally"? You're either running locally, or deploying it - not both.

Comment: Can you post your web.xml and appengine-web.xml?

Comment: I'd guess that JPA is innocent, just that that Google was a bit overloaded. Follow @Steven's advice. Is this still a problem?

Comment: I agree with @Thilo, I don't know what in JPA could be causing javac to run, but GWT most certainly would.

Comment: Which compiler version does it use ? This kind of javac hanging issues reminds me of 1.4 or sometimes 1.5 with the compiler hanging when the VM couldn't process the huge number of nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed. Its the problem with GAE as it takes a **6permutation Compilation** only after which the application would be deployed and shown on the browser. I feel its the problem only with GAE and not JPA. I have developed a similar app and if you feel its because of JPA, you can check the corresponding database admin to see how many threads are being opened for the user. If you seem to find some aren't Garbage collected, check your code. Else you can use ConnectionPooling mechanism (to speedup db retrieval using ORM).....

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on several parameters

- How you deploy, are you using eclipse or command line?
- GAE version (and GAE/GWT eclipse plugin version)
- Windows or Linux?

In any case, a [Thread Dump](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/Stacktrace/) can help seeing which non daemon threads are stuck.

For **command line** deployment in **Windows** - press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Break</kbd> after it hangs to get the thread dump

In **Eclipse**, if there is a way to deploy in debug mode, look at the debug view stack for the same info 
See this answer as well: [How to Force Thread Dump in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243298/how-to-force-thread-dump-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

This thing depend on which platform u r using

1. Windows
2. linux
3. mac os x

you can check what is going on by checksignal

> sending a signal

```
Usage:

SendSignal <pid>
  <pid> - send ctrl-break to process <pid> (hex ok)
You can get the source via anonymous CVS at

cvs -d :pserver:anon@www.latenighthacking.com:/code-cvsroot co 2003/SendSignal
```

Answer (score 0):

I have recently deployed my simple application in google app engine via eclipse. It failed to deploy couple of times. after sometime, It deploy successfully. I was able to access the application. if it hangs, stop the deployment process and redeply