# Tomcat hangs during webapp startup

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, soap, refactoring

**My *web project* was working perfectly, it includes: *spring3* and *hibernate3*. After renaming some packages in *eclipse* by the help of *eclipse refactoring*, *tomcat* could't start anymore. It hangs on these logs below:**

```
......
......
......

2012-02-29 08:57:04,552 INFO [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean] [buildSessionFactory] - <Building new Hibernate SessionFactory>
2012-02-29 08:57:04,567 INFO [org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory] [newConnectionProvider] - <Initializing connection provider: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider>
2012-02-29 08:57:10,698 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <RDBMS: MySQL, version: 5.0.77>
2012-02-29 08:57:10,698 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <JDBC driver: MySQL-AB JDBC Driver, version: mysql-connector-java-5.1.15 ( Revision: ${bzr.revision-id} )>
2012-02-29 08:57:10,729 INFO [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] [<init>] - <Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect>
2012-02-29 08:57:10,745 INFO [org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory] [buildTransactionFactory] - <Transaction strategy: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringTransactionFactory>
2012-02-29 08:57:10,745 INFO [org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory] [getTransactionManagerLookup] - <No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)>
2012-02-29 08:57:10,745 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled>
2012-02-29 08:57:10,745 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled>
2012-02-29 08:57:10,745 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <JDBC batch size: 15>
2012-02-29 08:57:10,745 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled>
2012-02-29 08:57:10,745 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Scrollable result sets: enabled>
2012-02-29 08:57:10,745 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): enabled>
2012-02-29 08:57:10,745 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Connection release mode: auto>
2012-02-29 08:57:10,745 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Maximum outer join fetch depth: 2>
2012-02-29 08:57:10,745 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Default batch fetch size: 1>
2012-02-29 08:57:10,745 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Generate SQL with comments: disabled>
2012-02-29 08:57:10,745 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled>
2012-02-29 08:57:10,745 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled>
2012-02-29 08:57:10,745 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [createQueryTranslatorFactory] - <Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory>
2012-02-29 08:57:10,745 INFO [org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] [<init>] - <Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory>
2012-02-29 08:57:10,745 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Query language substitutions: {}>
2012-02-29 08:57:10,745 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <JPA-QL strict compliance: disabled>
2012-02-29 08:57:10,745 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Second-level cache: enabled>
2012-02-29 08:57:10,745 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Query cache: disabled>
2012-02-29 08:57:10,745 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [createRegionFactory] - <Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.impl.NoCachingRegionFactory>
2012-02-29 08:57:10,745 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled>
2012-02-29 08:57:10,745 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Structured second-level cache entries: disabled>
2012-02-29 08:57:10,761 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Statistics: disabled>
2012-02-29 08:57:10,761 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled>
2012-02-29 08:57:10,761 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Default entity-mode: pojo>
2012-02-29 08:57:10,761 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [buildSettings] - <Named query checking : enabled>
2012-02-29 08:57:10,792 INFO [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl] [<init>] - <building session factory>
2012-02-29 08:57:11,244 INFO [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory] [addInstance] - <Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured>
2012-02-29 08:57:11,307 INFO [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager] [afterPropertiesSet] - <Using DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@1aac07d] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager>
```

**It hangs here, and when *tomcat's* "start timeout" reaches *tomcat* stops. I increased the timeout to 100 seconds, but it was useless, where the *app* still hanged on the longest times!
The strangest thing is that there is no error whatsoever, it just hangs. I tried a lot of times cleaning/deleting the server and cleaning/building the project, but with no result.**

**EDIT:**

*Before refactoring the log continued like this below:*

```
2012-02-29 07:52:39,822 INFO [org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory] [afterPropertiesSet] - <Creating SAAJ 1.3 MessageFactory with SOAP 1.1 Protocol>
2012-02-29 07:52:39,853 INFO [org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller] [createJaxbContextFromContextPath] - <Creating JAXBContext with context path [aheeva.webService.oxm]>
2012-02-29 07:52:40,571 INFO [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping] [registerHandler] - <Mapped URL path [
.......
.......
.......
```

**EDIT:**

*I got a thread dump with the following output:*

```
"main" prio=5 tid=0x001f9dc8 nid=0xf8c runnable [0x000bf000..0x000cfc00]
        at java.lang.String.equals(String.java:858)
        at java.util.HashMap.eq(HashMap.java:277)
        at java.util.HashMap.getEntry(HashMap.java:363)
        at java.util.LinkedHashMap.get(LinkedHashMap.java:273)
        at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.getPropertyDescr
iptor(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:275)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyDescriptorIntern
al(BeanWrapperImpl.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.isWritableProperty(BeanWrap
perImpl.java:407)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1327)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getOb
ject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        - locked <0x24682be0> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBe
an(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getType
ForFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1343)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:678)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeM
atch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:507)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:317)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIn
cludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:829)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:786)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanP
ostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.j
ava:474)
.......
.......
.......
```

*I can conclude the following:*

It's always the same *spring* hashmap in a *singleton* mode trying to fetch a bean and isn't able to find it for that reason the thread is *locked* ...very very strange! mustn't there be a *throw* for an *exception* or a timeout? weird *Spring* architecture!

Comment: don't show just INFO logs, but ERRORs

Comment: does it timeout after 30 or 60 secs? Can it connect to the db?

Comment: Delete that tomcat from workspace and add a new and try again:)

Comment: I tried all of that but to no avail! There are no errors, and the server still tries to start, but it stops at the timeout

Comment: What happens if you are running built and packaged application outside eclipse? If it is working you should clear the work and temp directories of tomcat running into eclipse. I do not remember exactly where it is located but I remember that eclipse creates its private copy of tomcat and "deploys" your application there. In this case you should find this place, remove it and create tomcat server in eclipse again.

Comment: @AlexR **I tried this, but still no result**.

Comment: @Xorty that's the issue, there were no errors in the logs whatsoever!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK I solved this: ***eclipse refactoring*** didn't change ***Spring***
`<context:component-scan base-package="package_name" />` blocks, for that reason ***spring*** couldn't find any wired components to treat. I found this by adding `Spring Tools -> add java nature` and checking in the ***Spring Explorer*** tab that `context:component-scan` blocks were empty.

Thanks to AlexR, mindandmedia, NIVESH SENGAR, Xorty and  Donal Fellows for your support and special thanks to nwinkler for the constructive instructions!

Comment: So… the autowiring was failing because it was scanning for the wrong packages?

Comment: @DonalFellows it was scanning packages that didn't exist anymore.

Comment: There is a bug in _Spring_, it doesn't check if the package names stated in `context:component-scan` blocks existed or not. And at run-time it doesn't throw any exception and keeps searching in its hashmaps for the non-existed packages!

Comment: In my case Spring was hanging after I added a bean definition whose class attribute was referencing a package instead of a class.  The package was existent.

Comment: I had just added that bean definition and the program stopped working so I examined it better (and then even better...).

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the following:

- Enable DEBUG logging - this will give you a better understanding of what the server is doing.
- Check the database for open connections to see whether the connection is established.
- Create a thread dump when the process is in this state. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243298/how-to-force-thread-dump-in-eclipse) or [here](http://expertodev.wordpress.com/2009/05/30/how-to-take-java-thread-dump/) for details on how to take a thread dump.

Comment: Tomcat server window having the focus I pressed CTRL+Break and it printed out the thread dump, now I'm trying to analyse the output...

Comment: go to tomcat/logs and take a look on catalina.log, localhost.log, stdout.log, stderr.log.

Comment: Check for long stacktraces (longer than a handful of lines), probably also containing some reference to the Spring, database driver or network/socket classes. These are common sources for blockers like this. It might be a network timeout issue, or a database issue...

Comment: What does the thread dump show if you take a second one after a while? Is it still at the same place or is it stuck somewhere else?

Comment: **There are alot of _locked_ lines like this one:** `at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        - locked <0x24682be0> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBe
an(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)`

Comment: can you see any pattern in the locations if you do the thread dump multiple times? Is it always in the same Spring or Hibernate code?

Comment: It's the same spring hashmap or something in a singleton mode, which is trying to fetch a bean and isn't able to find it for that reason the thread is locked ...very very strange! mustn't there be a throw for exception or something? weird hibernate architecture!